# User score not updated on loop

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm creating a pedagogical tool which helps students memorize the resistor color code. I'm using Tkinter for the GUI. This is the problematic function in my code:

```
score = 0

def nextResistor():
    global score
    global timeLeft

    x = random.randint(0,9)
    y = random.randint(0,9)
    z = random.randint(0,9)
    t = random.randint(0,2)

    xcolor = getColor(x)
    ycolor = getColor(y)
    zcolor = getColor(z)
    tcolor, tol = getTolerance(t)

    if timeLeft > 0:
        entryBox1.focus_set()
        entryBox2.focus_set()
        entryBox3.focus_set()
        entryBox4.focus_set()

        xguess = entryBox1.get()
        yguess = entryBox2.get()
        zguess = entryBox3.get()
        tguess = entryBox4.get()

        # Show the label

       if xguess == x and yguess == y and zguess == z and tguess == tol:
             score = score + 1

        else:
             score += 0

        print(str(xguess), str(yguess), str(zguess), str(tguess))

        entryBox1.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
        entryBox2.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
        entryBox3.delete(0, Tkinter.END)
        entryBox4.delete(0, Tkinter.END)

        rlabel.config(text=xcolor + " " + ycolor + " " + zcolor + " " + tcolor)

        scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))
        print(str(score))
```

For clarification, my function `getColor()` simply returns a string corresponding to the integer argument it is given. `getTolerance()` does the same thing, except it also returns an integer `tol`. Even when the user input is the correct guess, i.e. the condition is true, the score value is not changed. I'm currently printing guesses and scores to help my debugging process, but I've had no luck. Here's a sample of my output:

[image]

I suspect this is something simple, but I'm ripping out my hair trying to find it. The main loop in Tkinter essentially just re-runs this program while the time is still greater than zero.

**EDIT:** The real problem is that `xguess`, `yguess`, and so forth does not actually match what the user inputs. How do I resolve this?

**EDIT #2:** There is an offset between when the random answer is generated and when the user is prompted for the corresponding answer. In the program, the user is prompted to press 'Enter' to begin the loop. In the screensheet below, we can clearly see that the answer is given in the loop before the user is prompted for said answer. The output is in the form (answer, guess).

[image]

Comment: `type(xguess) == str  ;  type(x) == int`

Comment: I'd kind of have concerns that you are generating the random answer and getting the input in the same function, I.E. there is absolutely no time to type anything in between generating the question and checking if what is entered is correct.

Answer (score 0):

call

```
    xguess = entryBox1.get()
    yguess = entryBox2.get()
    zguess = entryBox3.get()
    tguess = entryBox4.get()
```

after the user has pressed return or create a button for submit then check then. The reason is you are querying the boxes when nextResistor is called, not necessarily when the user is done.

Comment: At the end of my program, I have `root.bind('<Return>', startGame)` where `startGame()` is a function which includes, among other tasks, `nextResistor()`. Is this not sufficient? I do see that there is an offset though between user input and answer.

Comment: Have you got IntVar set for entryBoxn? Are you sure you are receiving an int? you can cast with xguess =int(entryBox1.get())

Comment: I still think you are going to have issues because every time NextResistor is called you are creating a new set of random numbers for x,y,z,t then you immediate check the value of the boxes. I see nothing in your code that has the program waiting until the user has input the data.

Comment: I've adjusted for the difference in data type by other means, but yes I've solved that problem. I've made an additional edit to this post which I think is the underlying problem. The user already has to press 'Enter' to submit the answers, so how can I have the program wait for the user data?

Comment: From what I think you are saying that the you are in nextResistor for the entire time as required. If so put all your logic from  xguess = entryBox1.get() and below in another function and call it after nextResistor()